# Delete Insert operation depending on the record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting a record into database which updates after every 4 hours

The row has almost 30 columns and I am not sure how much columns will be changed it can be 4 to 28 columns. the only 2 columns remain the same i.e. `code`and `name`

What I am doing at the moment is first finding the row depending on the code if row exists then delete it first and then insert it again with new data. Otherwise the new row will be inserted.

Is there a better way to execute this?

Comment: too broad, be more specific please but in general all you do need is to update. Constant delete/inserts will cause your indexes to fragment really fast with possible performance degradation. Also delete and insert (general speaking) needs more resources than an update.

Comment: which version of sql server ?

Comment: Also there's not much difference in updating 1 or 99 columns, all the record is updated (there's again some indexes considerations for that indexed columns)

Answer (score 0):

you can just update it if code exists so that you can do only one operation(Updating) instead of two(deleting,inserting).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you first check if your record exists and then update or insert accordingly ?

```
if exists(select * from MyTable where Code = @Code)

  update MyTable set Col1 = @Col1, Col2 = @Col2, Col3 = @Col3
  where Code = @Code;

else

  insert MyTable (Code, Col1, Col2, Col3)
         values (@Code, @Col1, @Col2, @Col3);
```

Comment: If it's not a very old SQLServer version OP can also use `MERGE` instead of update/insert

Comment: Indeed, but on such simple cases I personally find this syntax easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

The merge statement is your friend, it can handle all three cases.
In you case, you have to handle only 2: `WHEN MATCHED` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`

```
MERGE INTO MyTable AS DST
USING (
SELECT
    @Code AS Code
  , @Col1Value AS Col1
  , @Col2Value AS Col2
) AS SRC
  ON SRC.Code = DST.Code
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET DST.Col1 = SRC.Col1, DST.Col2 = SRC.Col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (Code, Col1, Col2)
  VALUES (SRC.Code, SRC.Col1, SRC.Col2)
;
```

The `MERGE` statement is available since SQL Server 2008.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql